# Ace editor how to find backwards?

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I'm struggling with Ace editor in javascript.
My forward functions is working fine:

```
var selectionRange = editor.getSelectionRange();
var res = editor.find(/\?\w+\b/, { backwards: false, start: selectionRange, wrap: true, caseSensitive: false, wholeWord: false, regExp: true});
```

When I have multiple tokens on multiple lines, it finds them in order when I do multiple search.

```
?a ?b ?c  // First  ?a, then ?b, then ?c, then ?d
?d
```

But for finding backwards, by just changing backwards to true, it only finds the first element of each line.

```
var selectionRange = editor.getSelectionRange();
var res = editor.find(/\?\w+\b/, { backwards: true, start: selectionRange, wrap: true, caseSensitive: false, wholeWord: false, regExp: true});
```

```
?a ?b ?c  // First  ?d, then ?a !! ?c and ?b are skipped
?d
```

What is the correct way of finding backwards so that I retrieve all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp misses `g` flag. Either use `editor.find("\\?\\w+\\b", ...)` and let ace create the regexp or use `editor.find(/\?\w+\b/g, ...)`

Comment: What does this g flag mean?

Comment: g means global. Without it `"aba".replace(/a/, "x") == "xba"` and with it  `"aba".replace(/a/g, "x") == "xbx"`